# Cell grid not aligning in QGIS when raster calculator is used in model

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, qgis-modeler, alignment

I am attempting create my first model to automate some of my workflow. However, when using the raster calculator, the output raster is not aligned with the input one despite being referenced to the input raster. **When I perform the same operation with the raster calculator outside of the model, it works fine if I save the output to a file, but produces a similar error if I create it on the fly**. How can I correct the raster calculator output in the model so that the cell grid is aligned to the input raster?

Specs:

- QGIS v3.22.3
- Windows 10

EDIT: Further inspection has revealed that the height of the output raster is 1 greater than the input raster. What can I do to prevent this from occurring?

Misaligned rasters (input raster is the colored one peeking over the edge)
[image: Misaligned rasters]

Raster calculator in the model
[image: Raster calculator in model]

Model work flow
[image: Model work flow]

Comment: @BERA I have added a screenshot of the model workflow as requested. Regarding your suggestion, I have tried setting the Output Extent and Output CRS to the Input Raster, along with the Reference Layer, and the erroneous output is the same.

Comment: Nice! Ok. I have also had a lot of problems using raster calculator in models. Hope someone has an answer for you. The purple border isnt just values < 0 right?

Comment: @BERA I've confirmed that the colored parts of the Input Raster that are peeking over the edge of the Output Raster are values greater than zero.

Comment: Can you try filling `cell size`, `output extent` and `Output CRS`?

Comment: @BERA I've tried setting those to reference the input layer, but if you mean setting them to something other than that, do you have any suggestions for what might work?